# Read a csv file via JNDI - lookup (Spring, Websphere, Junit)

Tags: java, spring, junit, jndi, lookup

Wrote a Class that reads a csv file and does some operation on the data, and it works fine.

```
public FCSVReader(final UrlResource in) {
     try {
       final CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(in.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
       final List<String[]> csvContent = csvReader.readAll();
  --do some operation on the data--
       csvReader.close();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
     }
   }
```

Here is the test class:

```
public class FCSVReaderTest {
   FCSVReader reader;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
    reader = new FCSVReader(FCSVReaderTest.class.getResourceAsStream("abc.csv"));
   }
}
```

Now I want to read the same file using jndi resource lookup feature as I'm using Websphere. I'm new to JNDI.
Also write a unit test for the same by mocking this resource lookup. (Using Spring, JndiObjectFactoryBean, Junit)
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: JNDI lookup of what? What's the question here?

Comment: I have to read a csv file using JNDI. New to JNDI, may be I'm using wrong jargons, Please excuse.

Comment: You can't read a CSV file using JNDI. Review your requirement. Hard to see why you even have one given you have working code. You might want to look up its *location* using JNDI, but you can't *read* it that way, unless it is embedded in a server you can reach via JNDI, such as LDAP. Further clarifcation is required. You used to be able to read CSV via *JDBC,* but the necessary facility has been removed from Java 1.8.

Comment: I'm using WebSphere where I can add the resource URL. So I would like to get this resource(csv file) using JNDI.

Comment: No you don't. You can get it via resource injection. Your brief is inadequate.